# Recibir respuesta de un módulo BT en Android

Tags: android, c, programación-bajo-nivel, pic

Estoy acabando una app en la que a un PIC a través de un modulo Bluetooth HC06 le envío datos y los muestro en un lcd.

Ahora quiero implementar las confirmaciones, en la que cuando le llegue al pic algo, le envíe al dispositivo la respuesta "OK".

El problema es que en el dispositivo solo alcanzo a leer la letra "O", sin llegar la K.

Os adjunto el fragmento en el que leo lo que me llega:

```
        @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true){
            try{
               bytes=connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                String recibida=new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                String d=new String()
                System.out.println("RECIBO: "+recibida);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

es el recibida el que solo aparece el "O".

desde el PIC lo hago con la instrucción `puts("OK");`

Comment: solo estas mandando OK? ningun otro caracter?

Comment: solo un puts("OK");

Answer (score 0):

Intenta modificar la instruccion del pic. No uses la instrucción puts, mejor usa la instrucción printf, ya que esa instrucción es usada para enviar cadenas de texto.

Comment: Para  hacer una respuesta buena añade código de ejemplo sobre lo que propones como solución.